# HTML Auto Embedding Recent Uploaded videos from a youtube channel

Tags: html, youtube

I was wondering is there was a way to Auto Embed recent uploads from a YouTube channel to a website? I don't even know where to start. Help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube Recent Upload Thing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="static_video"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showVideo(response) {
            if(response.data && response.data.items) {
                var items = response.data.items;
                if(items.length>0) {
                    var item = items[0];
                    var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                    console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                    var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                    $('#static_video').html(video);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/urusernamehere/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to auto embed recnt video from playlist?

Comment: This has stopped working now. YouTube tells me they've deprecated this API, is there a quick fix to make this work with the new API version?

Answer (score 23):

Use the following code to auto-embed the latest video from a YouTube channel by specifying the channel ID instead of the channel name.

```js
var channelID = "UC0xXUfNSFQN3qOmf_G_nT5w";
var reqURL = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=";
$.getJSON("https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent(reqURL)+channelID, function(data) {
   var link = data.items[0].link;
   var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
$("#youtube_video").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="youtube_video" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Source: https://codegena.com/auto-embed-latest-video-youtube-channel/

Comment: As of Jan 2019, I have confirmed, this is indeed working! First time I found something that pulls in things properly and not just a live stream!

Comment: I was having loads of issues with the YouTube Data API authorisation and this works perfectly for my needs. Excellent solution.

Comment: This is still working in June 2021. Nice!

Answer (score 20):

This script no longer works, heres an easy way to do it.

```
<iframe width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To get your channel name click "My Channel" and its the line of text after "/user/".

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7ycmr7y/)

---

### Edit

You can also embed playlists with this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/+lastest?list=PLAYLIST_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with my channel. I don't have a channel username - it's a string of alphanumeric characters and looks like this: 'channel/etcetc'

Comment: @JCraine Check my answer for channel ID support

Comment: FYI to people finding this - If you are trying the fiddle or first option and it doesn't load, you might need to use https instead of http

Comment: Thanks! the playlist ID worked for me. You can find the list ID in the URL of the playlist after list=

Comment: I tried both solutions. The first one doesn't work anymore and the second one shows me the first video from the playlist but not the latest. :(

Answer (score 6):

In 2022, embedding the latest video from a YouTube channel is quite complicated, but I found a solution that works for personal accounts and [brand accounts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690?hl=en):

1. Login to YouTube and open the [advanced settings](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced)
2. Copy your channel ID (it will start with "UC" and then some cryptic characters, e.g. "UCYCJ5V6CYFhUr7AhlKaYL4A")
3. Replace the beginning "UC" with "UU" ("**UC**YCJ5V6CYFhUr7AhlKaYL4A" becomes "**UU**YCJ5V6CYFhUr7AhlKaYL4A")
4. Use the following embed code (using your ID that starts with "UU"):

**Embed Code:**

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=UUYCJ5V6CYFhUr7AhlKaYL4A"
  width="600"
  height="340"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

**Alternative solution for personal accounts:**

When you are having a personal YouTube channel that is connected to your Google Mail address, then you can use your Google Mail username to embed your latest upload.

**Example:** When your email is username@googlemail.com, then you can embed your latest video upload with this code:

```
<iframe 
  src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=username"        
  width="600"
  height="340"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Some say that it also works with your YouTube channel ID or YouTube channel name but this didn't work for me.

Reference: [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#Selecting_Content_to_Play)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution

```
const frame = document.getElementById("ytEmbed");
const channelID = "[CHANNEL ID HERE]";
var guid="";
            
fetch("https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=" + channelID))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        guid = data["items"][0]["guid"]
        const embedURL = "https://youtube.com/embed/" + guid.replace("yt:video:", "")
        frame.src = embedURL;
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```