# Embedding Youtube Channel uploads on a website

Tags: html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I was wondering how can you display the videos on a youtube channel to a website?

Here is a link [Image](http://www.andulicsdesign.com/Blakes/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-13%20at%205.58.42%20PM.png)

In the picture are videos off a youtube channel. Is there a way I can embed the same videos on to my website?

Any links or examples to something similar would be great.

Thank you

I've never worked with youtube videos.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267426/html-auto-embedding-recent-uploaded-videos-from-a-youtube-channel

Answer (score 1):

You'll use [YouTube iFrame embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/jeffposnick/yhWsG/29/

```
<div id="player"></div>

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '250',
        width: '444',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Yeah, i'll take a look at some of the examples. If I need help I'll come back.