# Embedding Youtube Videos Using Youtube API (Code not working)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

Working with API's tend to be quite confusing for me. That being said I found a bit of code at

[HTML Auto Embedding Recent Uploaded videos from a youtube channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267426/html-auto-embedding-recent-uploaded-videos-from-a-youtube-channel)

I am unable to get it to work for myself, What should I be doing to make this work successfully? I currently have code in HTML file @ https://foxumtv.com/videotest.html and as you can see it simply displays white page.

Thanks for any help I do apologize I am bit of newbie when it comes to webpage scripting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'd love to help you out but it's kind of hard without some more information. Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far and what exactly is going wrong? Make sure you check your developer tools (hit F12 on Windows, Opt+Cmd+I on Mac) for any error messages and include them as well.

Comment: Read the third comment on the accepted answer of the question you refer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the YouTube IFrame Player API on how to [Embed a YouTube player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player). Here, you need to use the `<iframe>` tag to your application in which the src URL specifies the content that the player will load as well as any other player parameters you want to set. To specify the dimension of the player, you can use the height and width parameter here.

Here is the example for that.

For more information, just check the documentation link above.

> NOTE: YouTube  embeds were deprecated on January 27, 2015.
>   Please migrate your applications to use  embeds, which can
>   intelligently use whichever embedded player – HTML () or Flash
>   () – the client supports.