# embed video youtube video feed

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm currently working with the youtube iframe API.

```js
var player,
    time_update_interval = 0;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        videoId: 'Xa0Q0J5tOP0',
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            playlist: 'taJ60kskkns,FG0fTKAqZ5g'
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize
        }
    });
}

function initialize(){

    // Update the controls on load
    updateTimerDisplay();
    updateProgressBar();

    // Clear any old interval.
    clearInterval(time_update_interval);

    // Start interval to update elapsed time display and
    // the elapsed part of the progress bar every second.
    time_update_interval = setInterval(function () {
        updateTimerDisplay();
        updateProgressBar();
    }, 1000);


    $('#volume-input').val(Math.round(player.getVolume()));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>



...<br>
<div id="video-placeholder"></div>

<br>...
```

So far it all works great but I want to display the latest video of a specific channel. I know it's something with user_feed but I don't know  how exactly to do it as I'm a complete js/api beginner.

Thanks

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267426/html-auto-embedding-recent-uploaded-videos-from-a-youtube-channel) if it can help you