# Embed recently uploaded youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to automatically embed my recently uploaded video from my YouTube channel in the sidebar of my website.

I got a good answer but it include user id they asked for
`youtube.com/user/SomeName` but in my case, it's like `youtube.com/CHANNEL/name`. I tried replacing "SomeName" with my channel id, but it didn't work for me

Comment: If youtube doesnt support channel ID's in their embed still you're going to have to embed using the video ID? Leverage the google API to get the video ID of the channels most recent upload, store that somewhere and have your javascript pull of that ID

Comment: you can try to load your channel's RSS , then parsing it with php to get latest video url / video id if needed.

Comment: @SkylineGeek You should include what you already have --- the "good answer" you already have. That will help others understand your problem better, so they can answer it, or so they can tell if they are having the same problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your answer. I found a pretty easy way to do this 
All you need is id for your upload playlist and to find that  visit google API explorer

> Services > YouTube Data API v3 > youtube.channels.list

fill in the part section with "contentDetails"
and id section with youtube channel id (the one starts with UC)
scroll down and click on execute

you will find

```
"uploads": "UUIprTMT-TDysEDx03YMcS5Q",
```

in ** "relatedPlaylists"** section 
copy that tag and now use this code to embed

```
<div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=YOUR_UPLOAD_TAG" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

[Test on fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hrjz6ojq/)

And you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed youtube channels or playlists, as said here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089630/7733026

> Here is how to embed a channel
>
> ```
> <iframe width="600" height="340" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```
>
> To get your channel name click "My Channel" and its the line of text
>   after "/user/".
>
> You can also embed playlists with this:
>
> ```
> <iframe width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/+lastest?list=PLAYLIST_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, many options have been removed from the API from V2 to V3.
A few things still remain, but are not going to help unless you know that it will be used.

One is the user name. Legacy Usernames are still around for channels that are old enough, but newer ones will not have them.
This is normally the `Title` of the page, but the title can now be changed.

This is where the ID's come into it. Everyone has a unique ID, but can have the same Tile as another page. (even if confusing some times)

Example of an old channel is Google
https://www.youtube.com/user/Google
The "user" name is a Legacy name.
But all channels old and new will have a "Channel" as well
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA
**Note that it will give you an ID rather than a name.**

So to get you what you are looking for, will need to be thought through.
Will the channel have a legacy user name? Do you need to show a name? or do you only want to find the last uploaded video regardless of name?

Best practice today will be to use the ID. Then with the API, get the relevant information that you need.

Step one is to call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails,id,snippet&id=[THE_CHANNEL_ID]&key=[apiKey]
```

The `contentDetails` section will contain an `uploads` portion.
This will be the user uploads to the channel and will start with **UU**
Though a short cut will be to take the channel ID starting with UC and change it to UU. But I would recommend the API approach for security and peace of mind.

Then with the uploads playlist ID (the one starting with UU), you can call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id,snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=[PLAYLIST_ID]&key=[api-key]
```

Normally the first in the array will be the last one in. The newest one. So setting  `results` to `1` will give only the first in the array.

If you want to do further checks to make sure, then set `results` to `50` and use the  `contentDetails` to dig the uploaded time of the video and select the newest that way.