# Auto-embed YouTube videos [Before last]

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, youtube

I know how to auto-embed videos on a website when there's a new upload. But I don't find the way to do exactly the same thing but for previous videos.

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=1&showinfo=1&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=EminemVEVO" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: What is the "before lasted" video?

Comment: i think he means the video uploaded before the last one.
some years ago i found a script to load a full yt channel as embed videos on a webpage dynamically but i can't remember where. I suppose that you can obtain a yt channel video list and iterate it. What i don't know is how to order, if possible simply order by date and print the second iteration

Comment: I was trying to mean that yeah ^^ The video uploaded before the last one ^^

Comment: Not quite sure if this is a dupe or not because you want to order them, but maybe take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267426/html-auto-embedding-recent-uploaded-videos-from-a-youtube-channel/30089630

Comment: I already saw this question, and that's not answering my question ^^ But thank for the time that you gave me :)

Comment: I still don't find the answer ^^ Someone know the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found !

With js and not only html : 
There's the [code](https://lc.cx/d8tm)