# embed latest youtube channel video to website

Tags: youtube, dreamweaver, youtube-channels

So this question has been answered, however I'm having a strange issue with the code.

This question originally answered my querie [HTML Auto Embedding Recent Uploaded videos from a youtube channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267426/html-auto-embedding-recent-uploaded-videos-from-a-youtube-channel)

With this JSfiddle giving me the exact working code that I need http://jsfiddle.net/j7ycmr7y/

`<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=albertsunzheng" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Popped the code into Dreamweaver no worries. Works fine and the site is almost done so I upload it and the code suddenly doesn't work.

Here's the code I've used uploaded

`<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=PewDiePie" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I've uploaded the embed code in exactly the same way the previous answer stated, plus it works on dreamweaver and browser preview.

Anyone have any ideas on why it wouldn't be working while online?