# iframe won't embed a YouTube channel's latest video (HTML)

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

so, I'm trying to embed "my" Youtube channel's latest video with iframe, using the code:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=CHANNEL NAME" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> .
```

while this works when i substitute `CHANNEL NAME` with my channel's name (`UCy3amHVg1fS_GBF8NSNlTAA`) it throws an error- however, when i substitute it for something like `pewdiepie` it works completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's only work with Channel Username, not with Channel ID. But you can make it works using JavaScript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45342740/11599531

Thanks :)